# SQL Server Job does not execute when scheduled, but does execute manually, how do I get it to run as scheduled?

Tags: sql-server, jobs, scheduled-tasks

I am running SQL Server 2014 SP 1 CU 5.
The job did work in the past. The schedule is enabled.
The account it is running under is an ADS account which has sysadmin rights and has delete rights to the folders in question. 
The same job, meaning the same step and only that step is in both, runs successfully on the test server.
The job deletes old backups, relying on the master.sys.xp_delete_file. Other jobs are running according to schedule.

I have re-created the job and still have the same problem.
I have changed the scheduled time to different times of the day.

Any ideas?

How do determine why the job will not run at the scheduled time given the information above?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Update the original question with information that has been requested.